# Excel formula to get table value on nth row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
 | ID | Email            | Username
1| 1    test@email.com     Test
2| 2    123@test.com       ABC
3| 3    bca@123.com        123
```

The table above is titled Table3

I need to get the value for the specific column (which is specified in cell A1 on the nth line).

So for example here is a work sheet

```
 | A           |
----------------
1| Email
2| =Index(Table3[A1], 1, 0)
3|
```

This should return test@email.com

However, Table3[A1] is looking for a column titled A1 rather than Email

Comment: I cannot even get =Index(Table3[A1], 1, 0) to be recognized as a valid formula.  =Index(Table3, 1, 0).  If I understand what Table3 is, I am assuming that it is a named range.  If I have identified it right in my test =INDEX(Table3,2,2) would return test@email.com.  Please clarify what you are describing to make it easier to assist you.

Comment: I think pnuts has your solution.  Your formula is attempting =INDEX(Table3[ [ Email ] ],1) where A1 contains the text "[Email]" in it.  Please see his solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
 =INDEX(INDIRECT("Table3["&A1&"]"), 1, 0)
```